# return sub-lists contained in a list,fixed size

Tags: python, list, split, sublist, chunking

How could I get (in a very efficient python way), a group of sub-lists contained in another long list??, I explain with example:

Let's say I have this:

```
List = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[2,4,3],......long list]
```

I would like to get an output grouping the sub-list in, let's say, in a groups of 7 sub-lists, then the output would be like:

```
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = [4,5,6]
L3 = [7,8,9]
up to L7
then process those 7 lists separately
and then start again....
L1 = [x,x,x] this L1 would be (obviously) the 8th sub-list in the big list "List"
L2 = [x,x,x] this would be the 9th sub-list....and so on
```

I dont know if I should call it like this but, It would be like making "chunks" of 7 sub-lists.

Is it possible in a fast and efficient way?

Comment: Dup: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with slicing. See [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) for more details.

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[2,4,3], ... ]

for i in range(0, len(list), 7):
  L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7 = list[i:i+7]
  ...
```

*Note*: the length of the list must be a multiple of 7 to do this. If not, append as much as `None` s to make sure it is divisible by 7.

Comment: Thanks bgamlath, this is exactly what I was looking for, works very good!!

Comment: Ans of course thanks to the rest of you who also gave a solution!!